# Getting a NameError when using Javascript in Rails shopping cart page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm new to integrating Javascript with Rails. I'm using it right now to set up a checkout button in my client's online store, following [this very straightforward tutorial](http://stillriversoftware.com/blog/integrating-stripe-into-your-ruby-on-rails-app/) that basically just [takes the code straight from Stripe's own documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout). And yet, I'm getting this error when I try to display the shopping cart:

```
NameError in CartsController#show
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Settings
Extracted source (around line #9):

6  </article>
7
8
9  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button">
10  data-key="<%= Settings[Rails.env]['stripe']['publishable_key'] %>"
11  data-description="Your payment description"
12  data-amount="<%= @amount * 100 %>">

app/views/carts/show.html.erb:9:in `block in _app_views_carts_show_html_erb__1517017895068716151_26976320'
app/views/carts/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_carts_show_html_erb__1517017895068716151_26976320'
```

Right now I've changed show.html.erb from the customized to the simple version of Stripe's payment form, but I get the same error with either one:

```html
<div class="shopping-cart">
  <%= render "shopping_cart" %>
    <%= form_tag charges_path do -%>
      <article>
        <%= label_tag 'amount', 'To Pay', class: 'amount' %>
          <%= label_tag 'amount', "$#{@amount}.00", class: 'amount-figure' %>
      </article>

      <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button">
        data-key = "<%= Settings[Rails.env]['stripe']['publishable_key'] %>"
        data-description = "Your payment description"
        data-amount = "<%= @amount * 100 %>" >
      </script>
      <% end %>
```

I can only imagine that I've missed something totally obvious here, but it beats me what it is. Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with JS, It's ERB complaining that it doesn't know how to look up the class/module 'Settings'

Comment: oh of course!! should be 
          'data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"'. Thank you!!